# Openerpv7: Numbeing in OrderLine

Tags: odoo

I'm using OpenERP v7 and requesting this below  output    in Purchase order line window

```
PO0001      PO0002    PO0003  
  Line      Line      Line
  10          10        10
  20          20        20
  30                    30
```

My code:

```
<field name="order_line" context="{'order_id':active_id}">

_columns={
'sequence':fields.integer('Sequence', store=True),
}
_defaults = {
 lambda obj, cr, uid, context: obj._default_sequence(cr, uid, context)
}
 def _default_sequence(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    max_sequence = 0
    if context.get('order_id'):
        order_line = self.search(cr, uid, [('order_id', '=', context['order_id'])])
        if order_line:
            max_sequence = max([line['sequence'] for line in self.read(cr, uid, order_line, ['sequence'])])
    return max_sequence + 10
```

But im getting this kind of output . Any advice would be greatful.

```
PO0001      PO0002    PO0003  
  Line      Line      Line
  10          10        10
  10          10        10
  10                    10
```

Anyone could help me to achive the required output.

Comment: try this max_sequence = max([line['sequence'] for line in order_line])

Comment: Hello i also not get exact output .                                   if you get correct output so please update your code

Answer (score 2):

I think you are doing wrong. A record will be created only after you click on any button action(button other than adding the lines) for the first time for the record. Then only you will be able to make the search. I hope default will get the context even if we don't specify context. Still not getting the context, then try by following the answer given by [Andrei Boyanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2982778/andrei-boyanov).Also please understand that field names like `active, state, sequence` etc have some **super powers** in openerp. For example if a table have a field "sequence", then the table's tree view will have a drag and drop functionality and if we do the drag and drop functionality, then a new sequence for each record in the table will be automatically calculated and saved.

So my opinion is not to use the sequence field. Use any other field name. Then  write a on_change method to your one2many field and pass the one2many field name as the attribute to the on_change method. Then in the on_change method check what all values are coming when you add a new line. If the new line's value is in the format (0,0,dictionary_with_fields_as_keys_and_its_values_as_values).Then to this dictionary add the sequence_number with the value.For example:

```
<field name="order_line" on_change="onchange_line(order_line)">

def onchange_line(self, cr, uid, ids, lines,context=None):
    result = {}
    result['value'] = {}
    #do the proper checking
    count_dict = {}
    count = 10
    had_seq = 0
    for index,line in enumerate(lines):
        if line[0] == 0:
            count_dict[index] = count
            count +=10
        else:
            had_seq +=1
    #seqnece_no is the new sequence field defined
    for k in count_dict:
        if had_seq:
            lines[k][2]['sequence_no'] = had_seq*10 + count_dict[k]
        else:
            lines[k][2]['sequence_no'] = count_dict[k]
    result['value'].update({'order_line':lines})
    return result
```

Please try it.

Answer (score 1):

How do you execute `_default_sequence(...)` ? I suppose you intend to invoke it trough the `_defaults` dictionary. In this case correct it as follow:

```
_defaults = {
     'sequence': lambda obj, cr, uid, context: obj._default_sequence(cr, uid, context)
}
```

In your code you omitted the key `sequence`. In fact what you defined is not a dictionary but a set with one element - the lambda function.

Better, you can define it just like this:

```
_defaults = {
     'sequence': _default_sequence
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your Python file by

```
def _default_sequence(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    if not context: context = {}
    max_sequence = 0
    if context.get('order_id'):
        order_line = self.search(cr, uid, [('order_id', '=', context['order_id'])])
        if order_line:
            max_sequence = max([line['sequence'] for line in self.read(cr, uid, order_line, ['sequence'])])
    return max_sequence + 10

_columns={
    'sequence':fields.integer('Sequence'),
}

_defaults = {
     'sequence': _default_sequence
}
```

No need to put `store=True` in the integer field, it will always store value in the database.

Comment: it's give me output like this for PO001 - 10, 20, 30................. for PO002 - 40 , 50, 60                                                i need it every time for every order from 10